# adding class and id in form_dropdown

Tags: codeigniter, select, drop-down-menu, codeigniter-form-helper

Is there any possible way of adding class and id attributes in form_dropdown of CodeIgniter?
I tried `form_dropdown('name',$array,'class','id')` and it's not changing anything, please tell me how to implement it?

Edited: 
with my dropdown form like this `form_dropdown('name',$array,set_value('someValue'),'id="myId"');` if I see my source from my browser it's look like this `<select name="provinsi" id="provinsi_id">`, but if I write like your way `form_dropdown('name',$array,set_value('someValue'),'class="myClass"','id="myId"');` than like this in my browser source `<select name="provinsi" class="myClass">`

that was I mean
thank you

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Like this:

```
form_dropdown('name', $array, '', 'class="my_class" id="my_id"')
```

The third parameter is for the value you wish to be selected and the fourth is for the additional data. Read [more](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

Comment: hi thanks @Yan for your time to answer my question, when I try like you way than I can't see for `id` tag..any suggestion?

Comment: Remove the comma. Like this: `'class="myClass" id="myId"'`. You need to seperate them only by space. Adding a comma makes the id a fifth parameter which the `form_dropdown` function doesn't have.

Comment: hahahaha..so stupid me, I did not notice it..thank you it's works now

Answer (score 0):

You can defined class, id or any other HTML attribute in the forth parameter of `form_dropdown()` function as an associative array like below:

form_dropdown('name', $array, set_value('someValue'), ['class' => 'myClass', 'id' => 'myId']);